# Why my whole table is not printing in javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a problem in `printing` the whole `table`  i'm able to print the `table` but only some part of it?why.

**i have 2 questions:**

1. Whole table is not printing , some part of it is printing
2. from my main `dom` or `page` `send status`,`send quotation` .. being **removed** `onclick` of **Print Table**  even though i have `cloned` into a `variable` to manipulate it.

**jsfiddle:**https://jsfiddle.net/uuxjv8s0/11/

**(PLEASE See JSFIDDLE as below Snippet is not working )**

```js
  
  $('#printThatTable').click(function(){
      var cloned = $('#examples').clone();


  cloned.find('a').each(function(){
    $('.excludeAction').remove();
    $(this).remove();
  });


cloned.printThis({
       debug: false,               // show the iframe for debugging
       importCSS: true,            // import page CSS
       importStyle: false,         // import style tags
       printContainer: true,       // grab outer container as well as the contents of the selector
       loadCSS: "path/to/my.css",  // path to additional css file - use an array [] for multiple
       pageTitle: "",              // add title to print page
       removeInline: false,        // remove all inline styles from print elements
       printDelay: 333,            // variable print delay; depending on complexity a higher value may be necessary
       header: null,               // prefix to html
       footer: null,               // postfix to html
       base: false ,               // preserve the BASE tag, or accept a string for the URL
       formValues: true,           // preserve input/form values
       canvas: false,              // copy canvas elements (experimental)
       doctypeString: "...",       // enter a different doctype for older markup
       removeScripts: false,       // remove script tags from print content
       copyTagClasses: false       // copy classes from the html & body tag
   });
  });
```

```css
      th{background-color:#f5f5fa;}

   td{background-color:white;}

   textarea{
    overflow: hidden;
   }
 form {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          display: -webkit-inline-box;   
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/printThis/1.12.2/printThis.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning" id="printThatTable">Print Table</a>

<table class="table table-boardered" id="examples">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
 <th>Id</th>

<th>Customer Name</th>

<th>Description</th>
<th>Order Number</th>

<th>PO Number</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Due Date</th>
<th>Billing Address</th>
<th>Shipping Address</th>
<th>Installing Address</th>
<th>Design</th>
<th>Production</th>
<th>Shipping</th>
<th>Install</th>
<th>Production Manager</th>
<th>Project manager</th>
<th>Sales Representatives</th>
<th>Shipping Method</th>


<th>Created At</th>

<th>Status</th>    
<td style="display:none;"></td>
</tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

     

 <tr id="deletetr22"> 

 <td class="notIdClass">AnsAhKR</td>

 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="22" data-table="customer_name">Raj Laxmi</td>
 
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="22" data-table="description">45x56 led board</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="22" data-table="order_number">2164</td>
 
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="22" data-table="po_number">45231</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="22" data-table="quantity"></td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="22" data-table="due_date">2018/01/15 16:23</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="22" data-table="billing_address">#141 narasipura bangalore&nbsp;- 560097</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="22" data-table="shipping_address">shipping address bangalore</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="22" data-table="installing_address"></td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="22" data-table="design">45x56 led board, 18x90 flex, 500 brouchers</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="22" data-table="production">back and front board 2 side</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="22" data-table="shipping">Call before installing</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="22" data-table="install">he needs to get installed on 17th - Jan-2018</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="22" data-table="production_manager">Saif</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="22" data-table="project_manager">Hemanth</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="22" data-table="sales_representative"></td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="22" data-table="shipping_method">mini truck</td>
 





 <td data-table="workflow" style="color:#0277bd">17-01-2018</td>



 


    <td class="statusNotClass">

      <p><span style="color:#ff9800;">Old : </span><strong>pending</strong></p>        
       <select data-edit="22" data-table="status" class="defineWorkflow">  
            <option value="">-- Select --</option>
            <option value="progress">Progress</option>
            <option value="pending">Pending</option>
            <option value="completed">Completed</option>  
        </select>

    </td>

<td>
 </td></tr></tbody><thead id="alsoDeleteThead22" class="thead-dark excludeAction" style="background-color: !important;">
    <tr><th style="width: 100% !important">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit Option</th>

      <th colspan="50 ">


      
    <a> <form action="http://localhost:8000/send_customer_status" method="POST">
         <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="nyUNxzIzFc4TJukPX8EGmPLvQGLf5Vu2HzR0yxVz">
        <input type="hidden" name="job_id" value="22">
        <input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="12">
        <button class="btn btn-danger send-status statusAlreadySent" title="Status Sent On - 2018-01-16 17:28:00">Send Status </button>
     </form></a>
     

     <a><form action="http://localhost:8000/send_customer_quotation" method="POST">
         <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="nyUNxzIzFc4TJukPX8EGmPLvQGLf5Vu2HzR0yxVz">
        <input type="hidden" name="job_id" value="22">
        <input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="12">
        <button class="btn btn-danger send-status statusAlreadySent" title="Status Sent On - 2018-01-16 17:28:00">Send Quotation</button>
      </form></a>

     <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger  send-invoice">Send in Voice</a>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger  delete-customer" data-delete="22">Delete</a></th>
   

  
  </tr></thead>
 

     

      

 <tbody><tr id="deletetr21"> 

 <td class="notIdClass">2PslfYy</td>

 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="21" data-table="customer_name">dsndfbbd ejaz</td>
 
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="21" data-table="description"></td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="21" data-table="order_number">2061</td>
 
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="21" data-table="po_number"></td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="21" data-table="quantity"></td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="21" data-table="due_date"></td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="21" data-table="billing_address"></td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="21" data-table="shipping_address"></td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="21" data-table="installing_address"></td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="21" data-table="design"></td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="21" data-table="production"></td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="21" data-table="shipping"></td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="21" data-table="install"></td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="21" data-table="production_manager"></td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="21" data-table="project_manager"></td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="21" data-table="sales_representative"></td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="21" data-table="shipping_method"></td>
 





 <td data-table="workflow" style="color:#0277bd">16-01-2018</td>



 


    <td class="statusNotClass">

      <p><span style="color:#ff9800;">Old : </span><strong>pending</strong></p>        
       <select data-edit="21" data-table="status" class="defineWorkflow">  
            <option value="">-- Select --</option>
            <option value="progress">Progress</option>
            <option value="pending">Pending</option>
            <option value="completed">Completed</option>  
        </select>

    </td>

<td>
 </td></tr></tbody><thead id="alsoDeleteThead21" class="thead-dark excludeAction" style="background-color: !important;">
    <tr><th style="width: 100% !important">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit Option</th>

      <th colspan="50 ">


      
    <a> <form action="http://localhost:8000/send_customer_status" method="POST">
         <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="nyUNxzIzFc4TJukPX8EGmPLvQGLf5Vu2HzR0yxVz">
        <input type="hidden" name="job_id" value="21">
        <input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="9">
        <button class="btn btn-danger send-status " title="Status Sent On - ">Send Status </button>
     </form></a>
     

     <a><form action="http://localhost:8000/send_customer_quotation" method="POST">
         <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="nyUNxzIzFc4TJukPX8EGmPLvQGLf5Vu2HzR0yxVz">
        <input type="hidden" name="job_id" value="21">
        <input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="9">
        <button class="btn btn-danger send-status " title="Status Sent On - ">Send Quotation</button>
      </form></a>

     <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger  send-invoice">Send in Voice</a>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger  delete-customer" data-delete="21">Delete</a></th>
   

  
  </tr></thead>
 

     

      

 <tbody><tr id="deletetr20"> 

 <td class="notIdClass">lNsbTEo</td>

 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="20" data-table="customer_name">eweeedm</td>
 
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="20" data-table="description">fdvjhdhd</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="20" data-table="order_number">1958</td>
 
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="20" data-table="po_number">445</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="20" data-table="quantity">3</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="20" data-table="due_date">2018/01/27 17:03</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="20" data-table="billing_address">fnhbbhf</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="20" data-table="shipping_address">shipping address by me</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="20" data-table="installing_address">installing address</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="20" data-table="design">design</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="20" data-table="production">production</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="20" data-table="shipping">shipping</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="20" data-table="install">install</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="20" data-table="production_manager">production manager</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="20" data-table="project_manager">project manager</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="20" data-table="sales_representative">kfgkk</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="20" data-table="shipping_method">shipping method</td>
 





 <td data-table="workflow" style="color:#0277bd">16-01-2018</td>



 


    <td class="statusNotClass">

      <p><span style="color:#ff9800;">Old : </span><strong>completed</strong></p>        
       <select data-edit="20" data-table="status" class="defineWorkflow">  
            <option value="">-- Select --</option>
            <option value="progress">Progress</option>
            <option value="pending">Pending</option>
            <option value="completed">Completed</option>  
        </select>

    </td>

<td>
 </td></tr></tbody><thead id="alsoDeleteThead20" class="thead-dark excludeAction" style="background-color: !important;">
    <tr><th style="width: 100% !important">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit Option</th>

      <th colspan="50 ">


      
    <a> <form action="http://localhost:8000/send_customer_status" method="POST">
         <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="nyUNxzIzFc4TJukPX8EGmPLvQGLf5Vu2HzR0yxVz">
        <input type="hidden" name="job_id" value="20">
        <input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="10">
        <button class="btn btn-danger send-status " title="Status Sent On - ">Send Status </button>
     </form></a>
     

     <a><form action="http://localhost:8000/send_customer_quotation" method="POST">
         <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="nyUNxzIzFc4TJukPX8EGmPLvQGLf5Vu2HzR0yxVz">
        <input type="hidden" name="job_id" value="20">
        <input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="10">
        <button class="btn btn-danger send-status " title="Status Sent On - ">Send Quotation</button>
      </form></a>

     <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger  send-invoice">Send in Voice</a>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger  delete-customer" data-delete="20">Delete</a></th>
   

  
  </tr></thead>
 

     

      

 <tbody><tr id="deletetr17"> 

 <td class="notIdClass">rNsqS7g</td>

 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="17" data-table="customer_name">Huli Mavu nv</td>
 
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="17" data-table="description">ejaz anwar kappa</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="17" data-table="order_number">4374</td>
 
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="17" data-table="po_number"></td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="17" data-table="quantity">45</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="17" data-table="due_date">2017/12/30 12:38</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="17" data-table="billing_address">d nddne</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="17" data-table="shipping_address">erjnherherh</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="17" data-table="installing_address">ehererhherh</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="17" data-table="design">ddnbbehberh</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="17" data-table="production">nfddfndfdfn</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="17" data-table="shipping">fdnndfndfndf</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="17" data-table="install">ndndndf</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="17" data-table="production_manager">sdn bbdfb</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="17" data-table="project_manager">nf dbhdfdfbb</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="17" data-table="sales_representative">ndfbfbdfb</td>
 <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="17" data-table="shipping_method">dfnbdfdf</td>
 





 <td data-table="workflow" style="color:#0277bd">16-01-2018</td>



 


    <td class="statusNotClass">

      <p><span style="color:#ff9800;">Old : </span><strong>progress</strong></p>        
       <select data-edit="17" data-table="status" class="defineWorkflow">  
            <option value="">-- Select --</option>
            <option value="progress">Progress</option>
            <option value="pending">Pending</option>
            <option value="completed">Completed</option>  
        </select>

    </td>

<td>
 </td></tr></tbody><thead id="alsoDeleteThead17" class="thead-dark excludeAction" style="background-color: !important;">
    <tr><th style="width: 100% !important">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit Option</th>

      <th colspan="50 ">


      
    <a> <form action="http://localhost:8000/send_customer_status" method="POST">
         <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="nyUNxzIzFc4TJukPX8EGmPLvQGLf5Vu2HzR0yxVz">
        <input type="hidden" name="job_id" value="17">
        <input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="10">
        <button class="btn btn-danger send-status " title="Status Sent On - ">Send Status </button>
     </form></a>
     

     <a><form action="http://localhost:8000/send_customer_quotation" method="POST">
         <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="nyUNxzIzFc4TJukPX8EGmPLvQGLf5Vu2HzR0yxVz">
        <input type="hidden" name="job_id" value="17">
        <input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="10">
        <button class="btn btn-danger send-status " title="Status Sent On - ">Send Quotation</button>
      </form></a>

     <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger  send-invoice">Send in Voice</a>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger  delete-customer" data-delete="17">Delete</a></th>
   

  
  </tr></thead>
 
</table>
```

Please help me with the above problem to get a solution, thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Not printing as in output from a printer or screen?

Comment: @zer00ne, it is not printing in output, please help me

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  $("#printThatTable").click(function() {
      print()
  });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#printThatTable").click(function() {
    print()
  });
});
```

```css
th {
  background-color: #f5f5fa;
}

td {
  background-color: white;
}

textarea {
  overflow: hidden;
}

form {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/printThis/1.12.2/printThis.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning" id="printThatTable">Print Table</a>

  <table class="table table-boardered" id="examples">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>

        <th>Customer Name</th>

        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Order Number</th>

        <th>PO Number</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Due Date</th>
        <th>Billing Address</th>
        <th>Shipping Address</th>
        <th>Installing Address</th>
        <th>Design</th>
        <th>Production</th>
        <th>Shipping</th>
        <th>Install</th>
        <th>Production Manager</th>
        <th>Project manager</th>
        <th>Sales Representatives</th>
        <th>Shipping Method</th>


        <th>Created At</th>

        <th>Status</th>
        <td style="display:none;"></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>



      <tr id="deletetr22">

        <td class="notIdClass">AnsAhKR</td>

        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="22" data-table="customer_name">Raj Laxmi</td>

        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="22" data-table="description">45x56 led board</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="22" data-table="order_number">2164</td>

        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="22" data-table="po_number">45231</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="22" data-table="quantity"></td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="22" data-table="due_date">2018/01/15 16:23</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="22" data-table="billing_address">#141 narasipura bangalore&nbsp;- 560097</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="22" data-table="shipping_address">shipping address bangalore</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="22" data-table="installing_address"></td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="22" data-table="design">45x56 led board, 18x90 flex, 500 brouchers</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="22" data-table="production">back and front board 2 side</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="22" data-table="shipping">Call before installing</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="22" data-table="install">he needs to get installed on 17th - Jan-2018</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="22" data-table="production_manager">Saif</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="22" data-table="project_manager">Hemanth</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="22" data-table="sales_representative"></td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="22" data-table="shipping_method">mini truck</td>






        <td data-table="workflow" style="color:#0277bd">17-01-2018</td>






        <td class="statusNotClass">

          <p><span style="color:#ff9800;">Old : </span><strong>pending</strong></p>
          <select data-edit="22" data-table="status" class="defineWorkflow">  
            <option value="">-- Select --</option>
            <option value="progress">Progress</option>
            <option value="pending">Pending</option>
            <option value="completed">Completed</option>  
        </select>

        </td>

        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <thead id="alsoDeleteThead22" class="thead-dark excludeAction" style="background-color: !important;">
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 100% !important">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit Option</th>

        <th colspan="50 ">



          <a>
            <form action="http://localhost:8000/send_customer_status" method="POST">
              <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="nyUNxzIzFc4TJukPX8EGmPLvQGLf5Vu2HzR0yxVz">
              <input type="hidden" name="job_id" value="22">
              <input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="12">
              <button class="btn btn-danger send-status statusAlreadySent" title="Status Sent On - 2018-01-16 17:28:00">Send Status </button>
            </form>
          </a>


          <a>
            <form action="http://localhost:8000/send_customer_quotation" method="POST">
              <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="nyUNxzIzFc4TJukPX8EGmPLvQGLf5Vu2HzR0yxVz">
              <input type="hidden" name="job_id" value="22">
              <input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="12">
              <button class="btn btn-danger send-status statusAlreadySent" title="Status Sent On - 2018-01-16 17:28:00">Send Quotation</button>
            </form>
          </a>

          <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger  send-invoice">Send in Voice</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger  delete-customer" data-delete="22">Delete</a></th>



      </tr>
    </thead>






    <tbody>
      <tr id="deletetr21">

        <td class="notIdClass">2PslfYy</td>

        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="21" data-table="customer_name">dsndfbbd ejaz</td>

        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="21" data-table="description"></td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="21" data-table="order_number">2061</td>

        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="21" data-table="po_number"></td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="21" data-table="quantity"></td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="21" data-table="due_date"></td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="21" data-table="billing_address"></td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="21" data-table="shipping_address"></td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="21" data-table="installing_address"></td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="21" data-table="design"></td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="21" data-table="production"></td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="21" data-table="shipping"></td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="21" data-table="install"></td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="21" data-table="production_manager"></td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="21" data-table="project_manager"></td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="21" data-table="sales_representative"></td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="21" data-table="shipping_method"></td>






        <td data-table="workflow" style="color:#0277bd">16-01-2018</td>






        <td class="statusNotClass">

          <p><span style="color:#ff9800;">Old : </span><strong>pending</strong></p>
          <select data-edit="21" data-table="status" class="defineWorkflow">  
            <option value="">-- Select --</option>
            <option value="progress">Progress</option>
            <option value="pending">Pending</option>
            <option value="completed">Completed</option>  
        </select>

        </td>

        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <thead id="alsoDeleteThead21" class="thead-dark excludeAction" style="background-color: !important;">
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 100% !important">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit Option</th>

        <th colspan="50 ">



          <a>
            <form action="http://localhost:8000/send_customer_status" method="POST">
              <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="nyUNxzIzFc4TJukPX8EGmPLvQGLf5Vu2HzR0yxVz">
              <input type="hidden" name="job_id" value="21">
              <input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="9">
              <button class="btn btn-danger send-status " title="Status Sent On - ">Send Status </button>
            </form>
          </a>


          <a>
            <form action="http://localhost:8000/send_customer_quotation" method="POST">
              <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="nyUNxzIzFc4TJukPX8EGmPLvQGLf5Vu2HzR0yxVz">
              <input type="hidden" name="job_id" value="21">
              <input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="9">
              <button class="btn btn-danger send-status " title="Status Sent On - ">Send Quotation</button>
            </form>
          </a>

          <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger  send-invoice">Send in Voice</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger  delete-customer" data-delete="21">Delete</a></th>



      </tr>
    </thead>






    <tbody>
      <tr id="deletetr20">

        <td class="notIdClass">lNsbTEo</td>

        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="20" data-table="customer_name">eweeedm</td>

        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="20" data-table="description">fdvjhdhd</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="20" data-table="order_number">1958</td>

        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="20" data-table="po_number">445</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="20" data-table="quantity">3</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="20" data-table="due_date">2018/01/27 17:03</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="20" data-table="billing_address">fnhbbhf</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="20" data-table="shipping_address">shipping address by me</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="20" data-table="installing_address">installing address</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="20" data-table="design">design</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="20" data-table="production">production</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="20" data-table="shipping">shipping</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="20" data-table="install">install</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="20" data-table="production_manager">production manager</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="20" data-table="project_manager">project manager</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="20" data-table="sales_representative">kfgkk</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="20" data-table="shipping_method">shipping method</td>






        <td data-table="workflow" style="color:#0277bd">16-01-2018</td>






        <td class="statusNotClass">

          <p><span style="color:#ff9800;">Old : </span><strong>completed</strong></p>
          <select data-edit="20" data-table="status" class="defineWorkflow">  
            <option value="">-- Select --</option>
            <option value="progress">Progress</option>
            <option value="pending">Pending</option>
            <option value="completed">Completed</option>  
        </select>

        </td>

        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <thead id="alsoDeleteThead20" class="thead-dark excludeAction" style="background-color: !important;">
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 100% !important">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit Option</th>

        <th colspan="50 ">



          <a>
            <form action="http://localhost:8000/send_customer_status" method="POST">
              <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="nyUNxzIzFc4TJukPX8EGmPLvQGLf5Vu2HzR0yxVz">
              <input type="hidden" name="job_id" value="20">
              <input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="10">
              <button class="btn btn-danger send-status " title="Status Sent On - ">Send Status </button>
            </form>
          </a>


          <a>
            <form action="http://localhost:8000/send_customer_quotation" method="POST">
              <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="nyUNxzIzFc4TJukPX8EGmPLvQGLf5Vu2HzR0yxVz">
              <input type="hidden" name="job_id" value="20">
              <input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="10">
              <button class="btn btn-danger send-status " title="Status Sent On - ">Send Quotation</button>
            </form>
          </a>

          <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger  send-invoice">Send in Voice</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger  delete-customer" data-delete="20">Delete</a></th>



      </tr>
    </thead>






    <tbody>
      <tr id="deletetr17">

        <td class="notIdClass">rNsqS7g</td>

        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="17" data-table="customer_name">Huli Mavu nv</td>

        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="17" data-table="description">ejaz anwar kappa</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="17" data-table="order_number">4374</td>

        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="17" data-table="po_number"></td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="17" data-table="quantity">45</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="17" data-table="due_date">2017/12/30 12:38</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="17" data-table="billing_address">d nddne</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="17" data-table="shipping_address">erjnherherh</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="17" data-table="installing_address">ehererhherh</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="17" data-table="design">ddnbbehberh</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="17" data-table="production">nfddfndfdfn</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="17" data-table="shipping">fdnndfndfndf</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="17" data-table="install">ndndndf</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="17" data-table="production_manager">sdn bbdfb</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="17" data-table="project_manager">nf dbhdfdfbb</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="17" data-table="sales_representative">ndfbfbdfb</td>
        <td class="editableDataClass" data-edit="17" data-table="shipping_method">dfnbdfdf</td>






        <td data-table="workflow" style="color:#0277bd">16-01-2018</td>






        <td class="statusNotClass">

          <p><span style="color:#ff9800;">Old : </span><strong>progress</strong></p>
          <select data-edit="17" data-table="status" class="defineWorkflow">  
            <option value="">-- Select --</option>
            <option value="progress">Progress</option>
            <option value="pending">Pending</option>
            <option value="completed">Completed</option>  
        </select>

        </td>

        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <thead id="alsoDeleteThead17" class="thead-dark excludeAction" style="background-color: !important;">
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 100% !important">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit Option</th>

        <th colspan="50 ">



          <a>
            <form action="http://localhost:8000/send_customer_status" method="POST">
              <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="nyUNxzIzFc4TJukPX8EGmPLvQGLf5Vu2HzR0yxVz">
              <input type="hidden" name="job_id" value="17">
              <input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="10">
              <button class="btn btn-danger send-status " title="Status Sent On - ">Send Status </button>
            </form>
          </a>


          <a>
            <form action="http://localhost:8000/send_customer_quotation" method="POST">
              <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="nyUNxzIzFc4TJukPX8EGmPLvQGLf5Vu2HzR0yxVz">
              <input type="hidden" name="job_id" value="17">
              <input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="10">
              <button class="btn btn-danger send-status " title="Status Sent On - ">Send Quotation</button>
            </form>
          </a>

          <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger  send-invoice">Send in Voice</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger  delete-customer" data-delete="17">Delete</a></th>



      </tr>
    </thead>

  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: it is not printing full table? can you check

Comment: its almost print all which portion not print tell me >?

Comment: these portions are not printing **Install Production Manager Project manager Sales Representatives Shipping Method Created At Status**

Answer (score 0):

Your table has too many columns that's why the table is not fitting inside the printing page,try changing the layout to landscape in your printing option, you'll see some more columns appeared.
Setting a smaller font size for table elements will print the whole table.For your table, if you set the font-size to 8px it will print the whole table in portrait layout but it's too small to read i guess however with a 10px font-size you can print the whole table in landscape and it is pretty readable.